# How to get rid of auto generated comments - sass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am new to Sass and Compass and I'm trying to figure out how to disable the auto generated comments when my css file is generated. Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of those comments?

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just delete them, like... backspace? Or are you looking to disable auto-generated comments from all your CSS files?

Comment: I want to disable auto-generated comments from all of my CSS files

Comment: The `line_comments = false` option in the config.rb, that disables them for the whole project I think

Answer (score -1):

Try using a hash (#) before the comments you want to omit